# Javascript function is undefined error

Tags: javascript, function, undefined, undefined-function

Hi following is my full HTML and Javascript code, but while running in browser shows error `Uncaught ReferenceError: draw is not defined test.html:13`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing D3</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3-v5.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function draw(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            draw(12);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You're missing a `</script>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use  self-closing tag apparently, change the d3 import to this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="d3-v5.js"></script>
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing D3</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3-v5.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function draw(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            draw(12);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```